# Can Grapher evaluate a function?

Tags: macos, grapher

I just noticed that Grapher fails to evaluate a function at a constant.  In the image, the graph of y = c should of course be a horizontal line.  Is there a way to fix or work around it?  This seems like such a fundamental bug that I can't understand why I haven't run into it before.

[image: Grapher screen shot]

Comment: you might want to try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Buscar웃: it's not a math question, it's a software question, so I bet they'd tell me to ask here.

Comment: Well, just assuming there are more ppl in the Math site using the Grapher then here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the problem is that Grapher assuming that the `x` in `f(x)=x^2` means the x coordinate.

To fix this problem, you should change the x to some other variable (say z).

I know, Grapher is weird sometimes.